# Jmeter or Gatling Kafka pluging that support google protobuf serdes

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, gatling, gatling-plugin

I am looking for a performance/load tool to test a spring boot app consuming and producing Kafka messages using Google Protobufs serializers, so far I've come across jmeter plugin kloadgen but I am not able to get this working.

With Galing I came across gatling-kafka-plugin but it looks like it does not support protobufs.

Comment: In Gatling Java (or Kotlin), you just write the function, which takes in a Gatling `Session`, to construct the protobuf message. It's just code. No special library necessary. For Gatling tests in Scala, the `Validation` type makes it slightly more troublesome to work with, but it's still doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For KLoadGen [Support](https://github.com/sngular/kloadgen?tab=readme-ov-file#-support) section says

> We’ll be glad to talk and discuss how KLoadGen can help you
>
> Reach us through [GitHub issues](https://github.com/sngular/kloadgen/issues), [GitHub discussions](https://github.com/sngular/kloadgen/discussions), [email](https://mailto:os3@sngular.com) or [Twitter](https://twitter.com/sngular).

In order to get comprehensive help here you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

So far I can only give you few generic hints:

1. If JMeter doesn't behave as you expect take a look at [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file. If worth [enabling JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for components/plugins you're using
2. JMeter is a pure Java load testing tool and it provides [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which is capable of executing arbitrary Groovy code, [Java Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler, [JUnit Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler or there is a possibility to [develop your own plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html).

   It means that you can simply take example code from [here](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/sr/fundamentals/serdes-develop/serdes-protobuf.html) or [here](https://github.com/zuowang/kafka-protobuf), adapt it to your needs and use in any of above test elements.